# Twitter bootstrap carousel- change slides with mouse scroll

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter, carousel

Is there any way to use mouse scroll to change slides on Twitter Bootstrap Carousel?

Regards

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As Barack Obama said: "Yes you can". The following code will do what you want:

```
$('#myCarousel').bind('mousewheel', function(e){$(this).carousel('next');});
```

Answer (score 2):

Maybe somebody still needs

```
$('#myCarousel').bind('mousewheel DOMMouseScroll', function(e){
            if(e.originalEvent.wheelDelta > 0 || e.originalEvent.detail < 0{
                $(this).carousel('prev');
            }
            else{
                $(this).carousel('next');
            }
        });
```

It takes wich direction mousewheel was scrolled to slide left or right